# 100% bg container img width issue

Tags: html, css

I don't believe my question is exactly as the others posted on this site, so if i missed one apologies in advance to this excellent community.

My question is this:

i've setup a hero container below the nav container in order to give it an 100% but when i reduce the size of the browser the image (in the background of the hero container) scales down and doesn't take up the full dimensions of the container. I don't mind if the image shifts due to the fact that it's increasing and decreasing in scale i just don't want it to become so small that the foreground content gets left without a background

Here is a screen cast that illustrates what's happening exactly:  http://youtu.be/lLT3VzHOlPU

Here is a codepen: http://codepen.io/MARS/pen/fEuKr

Thanks to anyone who takes the time to help out, much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The video is a nice idea to describe your problem. :) You can use this CSS on the `<div>` with class `hero-container`. The background image will always fill the whole space but will never get distorted:

```
-webkit-background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size: cover;
-o-background-size: cover;
background-size: cover;
```

See here, which browser support the [CSS3 Background-image options](http://caniuse.com/background-img-opts)

**Demo**

[Try before buy](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/mhqrC)